# ¿Cómo verificar usuarios en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy verificando usuarios al momento de ingresar al sistema, la cual ingresa normalmente si el usuario esta en estado "ACTIVO" pero al momento de cambiar de estado "INACTIVO" el usuario también puede ingresar al sistema, como puedo solucionar para que cuando el usuario al momento que este inactivo no pueda ingresar al sistema!! 
Espero que me pueda ayudar con esta duda, gracias.
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................ 
CONSOLA USUARIO

```js
function VerificarUsuario(){
 var u = $("#txt_usuario").val();
 var p = $("#txt_pass").val();
 if (u.length == 0 || p.length == 0) {
  swal("Campos incompletos!!","");
 }else{
  $.ajax({
   url:'../controlador/usuario/controlador_usuario_validar.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:{
    user:u,
    pass:p,
   }
  })
  .done(function(resp){
   if (resp==0) {
    Limpiar_post_usuario();
    var resultado="";
    resultado = 'Usuario y/o contrase\u00f1a no Valido';
       swal(resultado,"","warning");
       
   }else{
     var data = JSON.parse(resp);
    $.ajax({
    url:'../controlador/usuario/controlador_iniciar_sesion.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{
     user:data[0][0],
     pass:data[0][1],
     nom:data[0][2],
     img:data[0][4],
     usuario:data[0][6],
     codigo_personal:data[0][5],
     idusuario:data[0][7]
    }
    })
    .done(function(resp){
     swal({
       title: "Bienvenido",
       text: "Datos Correctos.",
       timer: 1000,
       showConfirmButton: false
     });
     location.reload(true);
    })
   }
  })
  .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

      alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

      alert('Requested page not found [404]');

    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

      alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

    } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

      alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

    } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

      alert('Time out error.');

    } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

      alert('Ajax request aborted.');

    } else {

      alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

    }
  })
 }
}
function Limpiar_post_usuario(){
 $("#txt_usuario").val("");
 $("#txt_pass").val("");
} 
function abrirmodaladministrativo(){
 traer_administrador();
 $('#modal_editar_adminsitrador').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
 $("#modal_editar_adminsitrador").modal("show");
}
function traer_administrador(){
 var codigo_personal = $("#txtcodigo_principal_usuario").val();
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controlador/usuario/controlador_administrador_buscar.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{
   buscar:codigo_personal
  }
 })
 .done(function(resp){
  var data = JSON.parse(resp);
  if (data.length > 0) {
   $("#txtoriginal").val(data[0][8]);
   $("#txtnombre_usuario").html(data[0][0]+" "+data[0][1]+" "+data[0][2]);
   $("#txtnombre_usuario1").html(data[0][0]+" "+data[0][1]+" "+data[0][2]);
   $("#txtnombre_usuario2").html(data[0][0]+" "+data[0][1]+" "+data[0][2]);
   $("#nombres_personal").val(data[0][0]);
   $("#apePate_personal").val(data[0][1]);
   $("#apeMate_personal").val(data[0][2]);
   $("#email_personal").val(data[0][5]);
   $("#telefono_personal").val(data[0][6]);
   $("#movil_personal").val(data[0][7]);
   $("#direccion_personal").val(data[0][9]);
   if (data[0][10]!="0000-00-00") {
    $("#fechanacimiento_personal").val(data[0][10]); 
   }   
   $("#dni_personal").val(data[0][11]);
   $("#txtimagen").html('<img style="width: auto; height: 100px;" src="../controlador/usuario/'+ data[0][3]+'"> ');
   $("#txtimagen2").html('<img style="width: auto; height: 100px;" src="../controlador/usuario/'+ data[0][3]+'" class="img-full">');
   $("#txtimagen1").html('<img class="user-image" src="../controlador/usuario/'+ data[0][3]+'" alt="...">');
   $("#txtimagen3").html('<img  class="img-circle" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;" src="../controlador/usuario/'+ data[0][3]+'" alt="...">');
   if (data[0][3]!="") {
    var cadena = '<img src="../controlador/usuario/'+data[0][3]+'" class="kv-preview-data file-preview-image file-zoom-detail" style="width: 41%;">';
    $("#id_imagen").html(cadena);
   }else{
    var cadena =  '<br><br><label>NO EXISTE IMAGEN</label><br><br><br>';
    $("#id_imagen").html(cadena);
   }
  }
 })
}
function abrirModalusuario(){
 $('#modal_cuenta').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
 $("#modal_cuenta").modal("show");
}
function Editar_cuenta(){
 var usuario = $("#txtusuario").val();
 var actual  = $("#txtactual").val();
 var nueva   = $("#txtnueva").val();
 var repetir = $("#txtrepetir").val();
 var original= $("#txtoriginal").val();
 if (original!=actual) {
   return swal("La contraseña no coincide con la actual","contraseña incorrecta","error");
 }
 if (nueva!=repetir) {
  return swal("Debes ingresar la misma contraseña dos veces para confirmar","","warning");
 }
 $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'../controlador/usuario/controlador_cuenta_actualizar.php',
  data:{
   _usuario:usuario,
   _actual:actual,
   _nueva:nueva
  }
 })
 .done(function(resp){
  Limpiar_POST_cuenta();
  $("#modal_cuenta").modal("hide");
  if (resp>0) {
   swal("Su cuenta fue Actualizada con Exito!!!","","success");
  }else{
   swal("No se pudo Actualizar su Cuenta!!!","","error");
  }
 })
}
function Limpiar_POST_cuenta(){
 $("#txtactual").val("");
 $("#txtnueva").val("");
 $("#txtrepetir").val("");
 traer_administrador();
}
```

CONTROLADOR USUARIO VALIDAR

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 $usuario = $_POST['user'];
 $pass    = $_POST['pass'];
 include '../../modelo/modelo_usuario.php';
 $MU = new Modelo_usuario();
 $consulta = $MU->Verificar_usuario($usuario,$pass);
 $data = json_encode($consulta);
    if (count($consulta) > 0) {
 echo $data;
 }else{
  echo 0;
 }
 
?>
```

MODELO USUARIO

```html
<?php
 class Modelo_usuario
 {
  private $conexion;
  function __construct()
  {
   require_once('modelo_conexion.php');
   $this->conexion = new conexion();
   $this->conexion->conectar();
  }
  function Verificar_usuario($usuario,$pass){
   $sql = "call PA_VERIFICARUSUARIO('$usuario','$pass')";
   $arreglo = array();
   if ($consulta = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {
    while ($consulta_VU = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
     $arreglo[] = $consulta_VU;
    }
    return $arreglo;
    $this->conexion->cerrar(); 
   }
  }
  function buscar_adminsitrador($buscar){
   $sql = "call PA_BUSCARADMINISTRADOR('$buscar')"; 
   $arreglo = array();
   if ($consulta = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {

    while ($consulta_VU = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
     $arreglo[] = $consulta_VU;
    }
    return $arreglo;
    $this->conexion->cerrar(); 
   }
  }
  function editar_usuario($usuario,$actual,$nueva){
   $sql = "call PA_EDITARUSUARIO('$usuario','$actual','$nueva')";
   if ($resultado = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)){
    return 1;
   }
   else{
    return 0;
   }
   $this->conexion->Cerrar_Conexion();
  }
  function editar_personal($codigo,$nombre,$apePat,$apeMat,$email,$telefo,$movil,$direc,$fecha,$dni){
   $sql ="call PA_EDITARPERSONAL('$codigo','$nombre','$apePat','$apeMat','$email','$telefo','$movil','$direc','$fecha','$dni')";
   if ($resultado=$this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)){
    return 1;
   }else{
    return 0;
   }
   $this->conexion->Cerrar_Conexion();
  }
 }
?>
```

STORED PROCEDURES  VERIFICAR USUARIO

```html
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PA_VERIFICARUSUARIO`(IN `_usu` VARCHAR(30), IN `_pass` VARCHAR(30))
SELECT
usuario.usu_nombre,
usuario.usu_clave,
CONCAT_WS(' ',personal.pers_nombres,personal.pers_apellidoPate,personal.pers_apellidoMate),
tipo_usuario.cod_tipousuario,
usuario.usu_foto,
personal.personal_cod,
tipo_usuario.tipusu_descripcion,
usuario.cod_usuario
FROM
personal
INNER JOIN usuario ON personal.usuario_cod = usuario.cod_usuario
INNER JOIN tipo_usuario ON usuario.cod_tipousuario = tipo_usuario.cod_tipousuario
WHERE usuario.usu_nombre = _usu AND usuario.usu_clave = _pass
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu query  en PHP donde haces la consulta del usuario, creo que alli es donde se puede resolver tu problema.

Comment: ya le muestro estimado....

Comment: Por lo que veo tienes tus consultas dentro de Stored procedures. 
puedes poner por favor esta
call PA_VERIFICARUSUARIO('$usuario','$pass')

Comment: YA LE AÑADÍ ESTIMADO...

Comment: ok, si checas la ultima linea dice:
WHERE usuario.usu_nombre = _usu AND usuario.usu_clave = _pass
te falta validar que tambien este activo, como no se cual es el campo supondre que seria algo asi:
WHERE usuario.usu_nombre = _usu AND usuario.usu_clave = _pass AND usuario.estatus = "Activo"
Pero te repito seria el campo que estes usando y como manejes los estatus, de esta manera traera solo los activos.

Comment: WHERE usuario.usu_nombre = _usu AND usuario.usu_clave = _pass AND usuario.usu_estado = "ACTIVO"  GRACIAS